# Descending order by using for statement in java

Tags: java, sorting

There is a list of 200 students names and exam results.
My task is: "Create a constructor method for this list and put them in descending order with for statement".

I've done the first part. I can print out the list also. But I have no idea how to put them in descending order using for statement. Can anyone show me how to do that?

Current code:

```
package training;
public class ExamResult {
    String studentName;
    String examName;
    int points;
    String date;
    ExamResult(String studentName, String examName, String date,int points) {
        this.studentName=studentName;
        this.examName=examName;
        this.points=points;
        this.date=date;
    }
    public void display() {
        System.out.println(studentName + " " + examName + " " + date + " " + points);
    }
}
```

```
package training;

public class DisplayExamResults {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        ExamResult one=new ExamResult("Ryan Pena","Sociology","21/06/2016",16);
        ExamResult two=new ExamResult("Portia Hamilton","Sociology","21/06/2016",34);
        ExamResult three=new ExamResult("Ryan Pena","Sociology","21/06/2016",35);
        one.display();
        two.display();
        three.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: @DanielBaker, you should edit your original post and add the code there. Use the comment section for discussion.

Comment: ok i will do that @RachayitaGiri

Comment: I have suggested it as an edit for you. But you should always post your code in the original post.

Comment: Also, the Java convention is to use capital letters for the letter in each word in the class name.

Comment: Ok got it thank you @RachayitaGiri

Comment: I post it in question now @ManojBanik

Comment: Do you want to sort them in the descending order of the student names or exam scores?

Answer (score 0):

If the names are as a String Array or a List:

Using standard Java libraries:

```
String[] students = {"Aaron", "Jonas", "Bob", "Karl"};
Arrays.sort(students);
List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(students));
Collections.reverse(temp);
temp.toArray(students);
```

**OR**

Using Bubblesort and chars to compare the strings:

```
String[] students = {"Aaron", "Jonas", "Bob", "Karl"};
    char[] temp1;
    char[] temp2;
    int length;
    for(int i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
        temp1 = students[i].toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        for(int n = i+1; n < students.length; n++){
            temp2 = students[n].toLowerCase().toCharArray();
            if(temp1.length > temp2.length)
                length = temp2.length;
            else
                length = temp1.length;
            for(int c = 0; c < length; c++){
                if(temp1[c] < temp2[c]){
                    String temp = students[i];
                    students[i] = students[n];
                    students[n] = temp;
                    temp1 = students[i].toLowerCase().toCharArray();
                    break;
                }
                else if(temp1[c] > temp2[c])
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok i'm new but i'm sure i said in the post that i'm new to java and i can use only for statement,i didn't get more than a half of your code.

Comment: Only "for" isn't sufficient to sort unless you can use java sort method for some class. @Daniel Baker

Answer (score 0):

So, Daniel! This is going to be long because you are new to Java and I will try to explain everything. You can always read more about a lot of things here but I will explain just enough for this problem.

When you want to sort objects of a class, in your case, class `ExamResult`, you cannot just use a for loop on one of the fields and finish sorting. In order to achieve your desired sorting, you will need to use an interface called `Comparable`. This interface lets you write your own sorting criteria based on the structure of your class.

We will proceed step by step.

**Step 1: Implement the `Comparable` interface in the `ExamResult` class**

Since you want to sort objects of the `ExamResult` class, this is where you will implement the interface. By that, we mean, you will write *how you want to sort your objects*. We want to sort based on the student names. And for sorting, we will need to *compare* objects to see which one is greater than the other.

Here, we will use a term called *overriding* which basically means that we will override the comparison function which was declared in the `Comparable` interface.

Our definition below takes as input an object of the class `ExamResult` and compares its student name with that of the current object - `this`. On comparison, it returns an integer:

- 0, if the names are equal
- >0, if the other object's student name is greater than the current one
- <0, if the other object's student name is lesser than the current one

```
package training;
public class ExamResult implements Comparable<ExamResult> {

    /* your previous code remains here as is*/

    // this function returns the name of the student
    public String getStudentName() { return studentName; }

    @Override
    // write your sorting criteria
    public int compareTo(ExamResult other) {
        String name1 = this.getStudentName();
        String name2 = other.getStudentName();
        return name1.compareTo(name2);
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Construct a list of ExamResult objects in `DisplayExamResults` class**

Now that we have finished defining *how* to compare objects, we need a list of those objects on which we will run the for loop and perform the comparison.

We can do that in the `DisplayExamResults` class like so:

```
    // Create a list of results on which you will run your for loop
    List<ExamResult> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    resultList.add(one);
    resultList.add(two);
    resultList.add(three);
```

Here, the `List` interface lets you define a list of objects of any user defined class like yours. So you create a list and add the `ExamResult` objects to it.

**Step 3: Sort using the for loop**

This is the final step, where you perform the actual sorting in the `DisplayExamResults` class. We will first sort in ascending order and then reverse the list.

You start with a left (`i`) and a right (`j`) pointer. `i` is set to 0 because it starts at the beginning of the list and `j` is set at the end of the list.

As you keep comparing, if the object on the left is smaller than the one on the right, you just move on, i.e. *increment* `i`. Similarly, if the object on the right is greater than that on the left, just move on by *decrementing* `j`.

But, if the order is not like that, then you swap them. Which is what we do in the `if` statement. You can see that we are using the `compareTo()` function that we had defined above.

```
        // Loop over that list to sort the objects
        for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = resultList.size() - 1; j > i; j--) {
                if (resultList.get(i).compareTo(resultList.get(j)) > 0) {
                    ExamResult temp = resultList.get(i);
                    resultList.set(i, resultList.get(j));
                    resultList.set(j, temp);
                }
            }
        }

        // For descending order
        Collections.reverse(resultList);

        // Display the results after sorting is over
        for (ExamResult r : resultList) {
            r.display();
        }
```

Phew! Now, we put all that code together to get the following two files.

```
package training;
public class ExamResult implements Comparable<ExamResult> {
    String studentName;
    String examName;
    int points;
    String date;
    ExamResult(String studentName, String examName, String date,int points) {
        this.studentName=studentName;
        this.examName=examName;
        this.points=points;
        this.date=date;
    }
    public void display() {
        System.out.println(studentName + " " + examName + " " + date + " " + points);
    }

    // this function returns the name of the student
    public String getStudentName() { return studentName; }

    @Override
    // write your sorting criteria
    public int compareTo(ExamResult other) {
        String name1 = this.getStudentName();
        String name2 = other.getStudentName();
        return name1.compareTo(name2);
    }
}
```

And

```
package training;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class DisplayExamResults {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        ExamResult one = new ExamResult("Ryan Pena","Sociology","21/06/2016",16);
        ExamResult two = new ExamResult("Portia Hamilton","Sociology","21/06/2016",34);
        ExamResult three = new ExamResult("Ryan Pena","Sociology","21/06/2016",35);
        one.display();
        two.display();
        three.display();
        System.out.println("\n");

        // Create a list of results on which you will run your for loop
        List<ExamResult> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        resultList.add(one);
        resultList.add(two);
        resultList.add(three);

        // Loop over that list to sort the objects
        for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = resultList.size() - 1; j > i; j--) {
                if (resultList.get(i).compareTo(resultList.get(j)) > 0) {
                    ExamResult temp = resultList.get(i);
                    resultList.set(i, resultList.get(j));
                    resultList.set(j, temp);
                }
            }
        }

        // For descending order
        Collections.reverse(resultList);

        // Display the results after sorting is over
        for (ExamResult r : resultList) {
            r.display();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to explain the bits in there. Please read more and understand better. Hope it helps.

Comment: If it helped you and answered your question, you can choose this as the accepted answer, @DanielBaker.